# How center my spinner when it rotate - CSS Animation

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I created a spinner in css and I put it in center without animation it works but when I start animation my spinner move away. Specifically When I use "@keyframes spinner" rule.
How I can keep it in center position?

```css
.spinner-animation{
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    position: relative;
    background: gray;
}

.spinner-animation > .spinner{
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: inset 3px 3px 3px red;
    animation: spinner 1.2s linear infinite;
}

.spinner-animation > .content{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    background-color: black;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 300px;
    color: white;
}


@keyframes spinner {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="spinner-animation">
    <span class="spinner"></span>
    <div class="content">Loading...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you all for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified the animation and added a `transform-origin` to the spinner :D

```css
.spinner-animation{
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    position: relative;
    background: gray;
}

.spinner-animation > .spinner{
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform-origin: top left;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: inset 3px 3px 3px red;
    animation: spinner 1.2s linear infinite;
}

.spinner-animation > .content{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    background-color: black;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 300px;
    color: white;
}


@keyframes spinner {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg) translate(-50%,-50%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg) translate(-50%,-50%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="spinner-animation">
    <span class="spinner"></span>
    <div class="content">Loading...</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the `span` in another container and apply `position: absolute` to this container

```css
.spinner-animation {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
  background: gray;
}

.holder {
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.holder .spinner {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: inset 3px 3px 3px red;
  animation: spinner 1.2s linear infinite;
}

.spinner-animation>.content {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 300px;
  color: white;
}

@keyframes spinner {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="spinner-animation">
  <div class="holder">
    <span class="spinner"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="content">Loading...</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Flex-box solution**: Display the parent element as a `flex` element, and align (vertically) and justify (horizontally) its absolutely positioned children to the center.

```css
.spinner-animation{
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background: gray;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.spinner-animation > .spinner{
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: inset 3px 3px 3px red;
    animation: spinner 1.2s linear infinite;
}

.spinner-animation > .content{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: black;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 300px;
    color: white;
}


@keyframes spinner {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="spinner-animation">
    <span class="spinner"></span>
    <div class="content">Loading...</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `transform` in your animation is overwriting the `translate()` positioning, you need to add `translate()` to your animation `transform` property.

```css
.spinner-animation{
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    position: relative;
    background: gray;
}

.spinner-animation > .spinner{
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: inset 3px 3px 3px red;
    animation: spinner 1.2s linear infinite;
}

.spinner-animation > .content{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    background-color: black;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 300px;
    color: white;
}


@keyframes spinner {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="spinner-animation">
    <span class="spinner"></span>
    <div class="content">Loading...</div>
</div>
```